# Webpack Dynamic Import inject into <body> instead of <head>

Tags: javascript, webpack, turbolinks, dynamic-import

I have a project where I use [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) in conjunction with Webpack's dynamic imports.

What I have is that the initial javascript file is as small as possible and then for each page, I load the relevant javascript code:

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const moduleName = document.body.dataset.route;
  if (!moduleName) return;

  const chunkName = moduleName.replace('.', '/');
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "js/pages/[request]" */ `@pages/${chunkName}`)
    .catch((e) => {console.error(e);});
});
```

Webpack's dynamic imports are injected into the `<head>` portion of the page which is great for any other use case where you want to load 3rd party packages. However, since I want to load a page specific script, I need the script to re-run on every page change.

Since I'm using **Turbolinks**, there is no page refresh. What **Turbolinks** does is it hijacks the request, and perform the request as an XHR request. Then, it replaces the `<body>` tag and merges the `<head>` tag.

Now the issue is that whenever **Turbolinks** merges the head, it will keep the per-page loaded script causing the script to not re-run on subsequent requests to that same page (remember, no page refresh occurred).

The best way I can think of solving this issue is to tell webpack to inject certain scripts (such as page-specific scripts) into the `<body>` tag as it gets completely replaced on each page (visit). In fact, this is what **Turbolinks** mentions in their docs to do when you have per-page specific scripts.

I tried to find out how to do it but was unable to find any resource about it.

There is actually another solution and that is to export a default function from every page-specific page and simply call that function after the import:

```js
import(/* webpackChunkName: "js/pages/[request]" */ `@pages/${chunkName}`)
  .then(p => p.default())
```

The only downside to this is that I have to remember to export a default function for each page module and my module code is always nested (due to being inside a function).